# Donations Paypal integration with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have been looking at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK
I have a website which needs to accept donations from PayPal.
Currently it is set up Donate Page -> Thank you page
But my understanding is that with PayPal I will need to do Donate Page -> PayPal Page -> Thank you page.
And I will need to get all the information in the thank you page for records.

How do I do this using this SDK? (Or any for that matter)

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) instead.  It's a lot easier to use, and if you do have questions, I'll support you directly.

Comment: Andrew Angell: How would I Use your api to get my website to accept simple donations? Do you have an example? Thanks.

Comment: You would use Express Checkout for that.  I have a demo/sample site setup here:  http://paypalphp.angelleye.com

Answer (score -1):

The documentation here seems clear enough:
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/master/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html